# viewBinding при создании нового проекта Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity, android-view, android-view-binding

Несколько вопросов начинающего:

1. Можно ли настроить создание нового проекта в Android Studio с использованием ViewBinding, что бы каждый раз не прописывать вручную:

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
```

2. Насколько понял в новых версиях Android Studio нельзя добавить пользовательские шаблоны для создания Activity (например создание аналога Empty Activity с использованием viewBinding), или же есть способ создать их?

Я нашел только создание шаблонов через `New Project Setup -> Setting for New Projects -> File and Code Templates` , например пустое Активити с viewBinding:

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME}

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import ${PACKAGE_NAME}.databinding.${BINDING_CLASS_NAME}

class ${NAME} : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ${BINDING_CLASS_NAME}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ${BINDING_CLASS_NAME}.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

но это работает только при создании новых(дополнительных) Активити. А вот как изменить изначальные шаблоны?..

Comment: При создании проекта в Android Studio Flamingo из шаблона "Basic Views Activity" создается то, что вам нужно: `buildFeatures { viewBinding true }`. Подходит ли вам этот шаблон? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: А так вопрос хороший, раньше все темплейты лежали в текстовом виде в директории, где установлена Android Studio в `plugins/android/lib/templates`. Их можно было редактировать или добавлять свои. Но в новой версии Android Studio видимо что-то поменяли.

Comment: Да, в целом создание проекта из шаблона Basic Views Activity решает и первый и второй вопрос. Создается, конечно, не пустое Активити, но с учетом viewBinding. Спасибо за наводку